# how can i combine different transparent images via pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import random 
def generate():
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (1000, 1000), (255, 0, 0, 0))
    possibilities = ['both trees','left tree','right tree']
    possibility = random.choice(possibilities)
    bg_bot_digit = random.randint(1,12)
    bg_top_digit = random.randint(1,12)
    currency_digit = random.randint(1,10)
    tree_left_digit = random.randint(1,9)
    tree_right_digit = random.randint(1,9)
    im1 = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\Msi Gaming\Documents\nft\bg top\{bg_top_digit}.PNG").convert("RGBA")
    im2 = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\Msi Gaming\Documents\nft\bg bot\{bg_bot_digit}.PNG").convert("RGBA")
    im3 = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\Msi Gaming\Documents\nft\currency\{currency_digit}.PNG").convert("RGBA")
    im4 = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\Msi Gaming\Documents\nft\tree right\{tree_right_digit}.PNG").convert("RGBA")
    im5 = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\Msi Gaming\Documents\nft\tree left\{tree_left_digit}.PNG").convert("RGBA")
    if possibility == 'both trees':
        img.paste(im1)
        img.paste(im2)
        img.paste(im3)
        img.paste(im4)
        img.paste(im5)
    if possibility == 'left tree':
        img.paste(im1)
        img.paste(im2)
        img.paste(im3)
        img.paste(im5)
    if possibility == 'right tree':
        img.paste(im1)
        img.paste(im2)
        img.paste(im3)
        img.paste(im4)
    img.show()
generate()
```

I made the images in photoshop and they do not go on top of each other but when i paste them to a transparent background only the last image shows up.Also size does also not matter cause all of them are made with a background which has 1000 pixel width and 1000 pixel height

Comment: If the original images do not have transparency then it won't work. Are you certain the original images have transparency or is it just a white background?

Comment: yes they re all transparent

Comment: Also, it is possible that you want this method instead: `Image.alpha_composite`.

Comment: i ll give it a try

Comment: You didn't say what you are trying to do. Or share your input images. Or share the expected result.

Comment: show example images and expected result.